# Adding Country FormHelper Bootstrap inside js not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add

```
<span class="bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true"></span>
```

inside my js script, but it does not show anything. If I add it in my HTML it works fine, but when I added in some several ways one of this is

```
var flag = document.createElement("span");
flag.setAttribute("class", "bfh-countries" );
flag.setAttribute("data-country", "US" );
flag.setAttribute("data-flags", "true" );
```

I think is possible that the css and js needed for data-countries are not loaded yet when this script is running, but both scripts are above this code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your node to the body
document.body.append(flag)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select your element.

Try this -

```
var flag = document.createElement("span");
var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
tag.setAttribute("class", "bfh-countries" );
tag.setAttribute("data-country", "US" );
tag.setAttribute("data-flags", "true" );
```

Not tested,  hope it will work.
Note that this technique will select all the span.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code.

```js
   

 function addNew() {
        var flag = document.createElement("SPAN");
        flag.setAttribute("class", "bfh-countries");
        flag.setAttribute("data-country", "US");
        flag.setAttribute("data-flags", "true");

        document.getElementById('result').appendChild(flag);
        
        $("form select.bfh-countries, span.bfh-countries, div.bfh-countries").each(function () {
            var b;
            b = $(this),
            b.hasClass("bfh-selectbox") && b.bfhselectbox(b.data()),
            b.bfhcountries(b.data())
        })
    }
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addNew()">Add Flag</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: "b.bfhselectcountries is not a function". I got this error

Comment: is all js library reference are available in your code? it requires bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js